# How to save excel created in powershell (not imported)

Tags: excel, powershell

i'm creating a new excel with this code:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.add()
```

once finished, when I want to save it using a SaveAs method that lot of articles mentioned, but this method doesn't exists in $excel.

How can I save an excel file created from powershell?

Comment: you are not trying to save the excel application but the workbook.  So try $workbook.SaveAs()

Comment: Ops, you're right. My mistake!